# black artifacts when baking ambient occlusion

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

When I bake with the bake mode "ambient occlusion" it ends in a horrible result.

[image: "Front View"]

[image: "Right View"]

Anyone know the reason why this is happening?

PS: It worked yesterday. I just opened it today and the model was black, so I 
    hit bake again and it was then it happened.

Answer (score 3):

I found it out. I had two objects on top of each other.